# Linq to query data between 2 dates when within a group

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime, linq-to-entities

I am trying to query my MS SQL database, using Linq. The code is

```
var ids = (from o in _visitDetail
                   group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
                   where (grouped.Max(s => s.DateTime) - grouped.Min(s => s.DateTime)).TotalDays > 0
                   select grouped);
```

This results in an exception being thrown:

> "DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type."

I assume it doesn't think the types are the same, so I need to convert them to DateTime so it's super clear for the Linq.

```
var ids = (from o in _visitDetail
                   group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
                   where (grouped.Max(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.DateTime)) - grouped.Min(s => Convert.ToDateTime(s.DateTime))).TotalDays > 0
                   select grouped);
```

Another exception:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

What do I need to do to query between these ranges?

Comment: Try "group.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).First()" and "group.OrderByAscending(t=>t.Date).First()" and then do the date substract.

Comment: @PreyashDesai, this will remove the `Max()` and 'Min()' though?

Comment: yes you should not need Max/min after using decending/ascending. Basically you are ordering the elements and then picking the first element which will be your max or min

Comment: @PreyashDesai, this has nothing to do with the issue I think... It will still the same type?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performing arithmetic operations with Dates and Times is **not supported** in EF. EntityFramework cannot convert your code to SQL. Instead of that you can use `EntityFunctions.DiffDays( startExpression, endExpression)` method:

```
var ids = from o in _visitDetail
          group o by o.CompanyId into grouped
          where (EntityFunctions.DiffDays(grouped.Min(s => s.DateTime), grouped.Max(s => s.DateTime))) > 0
          select grouped;
```

***Additional info:***

[`EntityFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.100).aspx) methods are called ***canonical functions***. And these are a set of functions, which are supported by all Entity Framework providers. These canonical functions will be translated to the corresponding data source functionality for the provider. Canonical functions are the preferred way to access functionality outside the core language, because they keep the queries  portable.

You can find all canonical functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738626(v=vs.110).aspx) and all Date and Time Canonical Functions [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563(v=vs.110).aspx).

*Don't forget* to add a reference to `System.Data.Objects` and to `System.Data.Entity`.

Comment: I needed a reference to System.Data.Entity! :)

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions I have forgot to reverse expression orders. )) As I indicated in my answer the first is start and the other is end expression.

Comment: And a reference to `system.data.objects`!

Comment: If someone is using newer versions of MVC, use `DbFunctions` from `System.Data.Entity` rather than `EntityFunctions` :)